# EF Core Including Other Entities (Generic Repository pattern)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, include, ef-code-first, repository-pattern

I'm using  Generic repository /UoW patter in my application c#
I was using EF6 ,then i moved to EF core .
My app worked well excpet for some reason my includes doesn't work , and i got exception

Interface :

```
TEntity GetFirstOrDefault(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes);
```

Implementation (EF core):

```
    public virtual TEntity GetFirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, 
                            params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

        query = includes.Aggregate(query, (current, item) => EvaluateInclude(current, item));
        return query.FirstOrDefault(filter);
    }
```

In Entity Framework EF6 , it was :

```
        foreach (Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> include in includes)
            query = query.Include(include);
```

The EvaluateInclude function is :

```
private IQueryable<TEntity> EvaluateInclude(IQueryable<TEntity> current, Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> item)
    {
        if (item.Body is MethodCallExpression)
        {
            var arguments = ((MethodCallExpression)item.Body).Arguments;
            if (arguments.Count > 1)
            {
                var navigationPath = string.Empty;
                for (var i = 0; i < arguments.Count; i++)
                {
                    var arg = arguments[i];
                    var path = arg.ToString().Substring(arg.ToString().IndexOf('.') + 1);

                    navigationPath += (i > 0 ? "." : string.Empty) + path;
                }
                return current.Include(navigationPath);
            }
        }

        return current.Include(item);
    }
```

When  I call GetFirstOrDefault function like this way , it works :

```
internal Domain.Entities.Project GetProject(int projectId)
    {
        Expression<Func<Domain.Entities.Project, bool>> funcWhere = j => (!j.IsDisabled && j.ProjectId == projectId);
      return  UnitOfWork.Repository<Domain.Entities.Project>().GetFirstOrDefault(funcWhere,
            p => p.StatusProject,
            p => p.ProjectRoles.Select(t => t.Employee),
            //p => p.ProjectTeams.Select(t => t.Team.TeamEmployees.Select(e => e.Employee)),
            );

    }
```

But when I un-comment the extra include , it fails :

```
 internal Domain.Entities.Project GetProject(int projectId)
    {
        Expression<Func<Domain.Entities.Project, bool>> funcWhere = j => (!j.IsDisabled && j.ProjectId == projectId);
      return  UnitOfWork.Repository<Domain.Entities.Project>().GetFirstOrDefault(funcWhere,
            p => p.StatusProject,
            p => p.ProjectRoles.Select(t => t.Employee),
            p => p.ProjectTeams.Select(t => t.Team.TeamEmployees.Select(e => e.Employee)),
            );

    }
```

> System.InvalidOperationExceptionInvalid include path:
> 'Project.ProjectTeams.Team.TeamEmployees.Select(e => e.Employee)' -
> couldn't find navigation for: 'Select(e => e'

[image]

Comment: the error happens in .Select(e=>e.Employee) : couldn't find navigation for: Select(e=>e.Employee

Comment: You're using the old `Include` syntax.

Comment: Are you sure `Team.TeamEmployees` is hooked up to EF correctly?  Can you use `TeamEmployees` with EF queries in any way at all?

Comment: @KirkWoll , yes . With EF6 it was working fine ,I get my project with projectTeam that has a team and inside the team there are employees.

Comment: @GertArnold can you give me how to change it tho the new one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :

following this answer [link](https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/47052419/how-to-pass-lambda--include--with-multiple-levels-in-entity-framework-core-)
I added this code that parse my lambda expression of includes :

```
    // This method is a slight modification of EF6 source code
    private bool TryParsePath(Expression expression, out string path)
    {
        path = null;
        var withoutConvert = RemoveConvert(expression);
        var memberExpression = withoutConvert as MemberExpression;
        var callExpression = withoutConvert as MethodCallExpression;

        if (memberExpression != null)
        {
            var thisPart = memberExpression.Member.Name;
            string parentPart;
            if (!TryParsePath(memberExpression.Expression, out parentPart))
            {
                return false;
            }
            path = parentPart == null ? thisPart : (parentPart + "." + thisPart);
        }
        else if (callExpression != null)
        {
            if (callExpression.Method.Name == "Select"
                && callExpression.Arguments.Count == 2)
            {
                string parentPart;
                if (!TryParsePath(callExpression.Arguments[0], out parentPart))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                if (parentPart != null)
                {
                    var subExpression = callExpression.Arguments[1] as LambdaExpression;
                    if (subExpression != null)
                    {
                        string thisPart;
                        if (!TryParsePath(subExpression.Body, out thisPart))
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                        if (thisPart != null)
                        {
                            path = parentPart + "." + thisPart;
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (callExpression.Method.Name == "Where")
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("Filtering an Include expression is not supported");
            }
            else if (callExpression.Method.Name == "OrderBy" || callExpression.Method.Name == "OrderByDescending")
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("Ordering an Include expression is not supported");
            }
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    // Removes boxing
    private Expression RemoveConvert(Expression expression)
    {
        while (expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert
               || expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.ConvertChecked)
        {
            expression = ((UnaryExpression)expression).Operand;
        }

        return expression;
    }

    #endregion
```

Then change my **EvaluateInclude** function to :

```
  private IQueryable<TEntity> EvaluateInclude(IQueryable<TEntity> current, Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> item)
    {
        if (item.Body is MethodCallExpression)
        {
            string path;
            TryParsePath(item.Body, out path);
            return current.Include(path);

        }

        return current.Include(item);
    }
```

And it works